# Word usage of "not to fly" vs "to not fly "

Tags: word-order, negation, infinitives, is-it-a-rule

I often read the phrase "not to" preceding an action, as in "not to run" or "not to swim".
It seems awkward. Please explain explain the usage.

Comment: As a general practice, people try not to [split infinitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive). ;)

Comment: As a general practice, please feel free to split all the infinitives it makes sense to split. There is absolutely no reason not to. @safetypat Why does _not to run_ seem awkward to use? It is simply a negation of _to run_.

Comment: @Janus I still find it grates. Even 50+ years after being 'To be or not to be'd'. The to-infinitive pairing is a strange beast, and negation doesn't make it [sound] any less strange. Regarding the OP's question about ordering, see answer below.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which version is it you find grating? The split or the unsplit one?

Comment: @@Edwin: Hamlet aside, Google Books thinks there are about 60,500 results for [*to vote or **not to** vote*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+vote+or+not+to+vote%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but only 8 for [*to vote or **to not** vote*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+vote+or+to+not+vote%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), so I guess you'd better just get used to the former. Not that I think avoiding the split infinitive is much of a "cardinal principle".

Comment: I was speaking about the normally accepted version ('Not to fly would make me sad') but the other is of course even worse.

Answer (score 2):

More than one usage of 'to' exists. Restricting analysis to *to + infinitive*, note the difference between

> Not to be charged the full price would be great.

and

> To not be charged the full price, make sure you show your
>   concessionary pass.

The second example here uses the 'in order [not] to' sense. Possibly, positioning has evolved to show the distinction where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the negative to-infinitive is normally not to do ( do stands for any verb) as used by Hamlet:

to be or not to be

I don't see anything awkward as to this form.

Occasionally you find an alternative form: to not do.
But there is no difference. Of course, there may be sentences where the latter form
is justfied stylistically.